# Awk : Select only row with digits in a column and multiply those for 1000

Tags: awk

**AIM**

I would like to multiply column $3 rows-digits (0.16 and -0.45) for 1000!
This avoiding to multiply the N/A for 0, producing a 0 where the N/A was!

**Command lines I am trying to produce!**

```
awk -F"\t" '{OFS="\t"}{print $1, $2, $3~/^[0-9]{3}$*1000/}' > out-put.txt
```

```
awk -F"\t" '{OFS="\t"}{print $1, $2, $3~/^%[0-9]%/$*1000}' > out-put.txt
```

**FILE**

I have a file with 3 columns :

```
abc  cat   0.16
lmm  fil   N/A
lmd  ful  -0.45
....continue
```

**Out-put searched**

```
abc  cat   160
lmm  fil   N/A
lmd  ful  -450
....continue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an `awk` solution that checks whether `$3` is numeric before multiplying it with `1000`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $3 == $3+0 {$3 *= 1000} 1' file

abc cat 160
lmm fil N/A
lmd ful -450
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Use ternary operator to check if 3rd field is NOT `N/A` then multiply 1000 to it else leave it as it is.

```
awk '{$3=$3!="N/A"?$3 * 1000:$3} 1' Input_file
```

***OR*** In case your Input_file is tab delimited then try following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{$3=$3!="N/A"?$3 * 1000:$3} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk`

```
awk '$3!="N/A"{$3*=1000}1' $file | column -t
```

**Output**

```
abc  cat  160
lmm  fil  N/A
lmd  ful  -450
```

Comment: where is the input coming rrom (-;?